# how to return '*' (asterisk) which appears at the end of required fields

Tags: dom, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The * does not appear in the text or any attribute of the label element, but it shows on the page.

Is there a way to verify that it's there in the page using Selenium?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible scenario. It mostly depends on css and styling/similar techniques

Comment: @Saifur - Yes, I got it. It's coming from css image. Thanks mate.